# Linking C libraries in Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I built C code separately and have libperson.a output. I want to include this library into my xcode project.
Added this .a under “Link Binary with Libraries” to my project.

```
#import "person.h"
```

It can't find the person.h. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just linked your project against the library. You haven't add that header file from that library to your project. Either add to your to project directly or configure the Header Search Path settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add the header file(s) to you project.  Or, if the headers are better off somewhere else, you need to add a Header Search Path to your Xcode target's Build Settings; in that way Xcode can find them.

Coming from Java: C has header files in which you typically declare public interfaces of a matching source file.  Where in Java you have `import` after which the compiler sorts it all out for you **from the binaries**, in C you need to `#include` the public definitions as header **at the source file level**.

Comment: is there no way to link .so or .a libraries? I cant attach the source coz it has huge set of dependencies

Comment: @Taranfx Not finding a header file happens in a compilation stage well before linking. So your current problem has nothing to do with linking as such. Are you familiair with C compiler stages?

Comment: @Taranfx I've added some explanation how Java and C differ.  If you need more details I kindly point you to wikipedia or just do a google search (instead of me repeating what's available online). HTH and good luck!  I understand your pain.